# Sendmail with Ubuntu and PHP

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, sendmail

I'm trying to get `Bitnami Magento` to send email on an `AWS EC2 Ubuntu` instance.  Before dealing with the `Magento` configuration I am just trying to get `php` to send mail.

This works

```
echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail toemail@mydomain.com
```

This doesn't

```
<?php
    $to = 'toemail@mydomain.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: fromemail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: fromemail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It doesn't work from the browser or if I run it from SSH, like this

```
$php my_php_email_test.php
```

It gives this error

```
sh: 1: /usr/bin/sendmail: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you specify the path to sandmail directly:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

When you run PHP code, the path to sandmail comes from **php.ini**. Try to change **sendmail_path** in **php.ini** from /usr/bin/sendmail to /usr/sbin/sendmail.

Comment: The path I the ini file was correct but it was commented out.  This helped me find that.